# passport strategy is not invoking while using passport-oauth2 in nestjs

Tags: nestjs, passport.js, passport-local, passport-google-oauth, nestjs-passport

auth.controller.ts:

```js
import { Controller, Get, Req, Res, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}
  @Get()
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('oauth2'))
  async login() {
    return 'hello world'
  }
  @Get('callback')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('oauth2'))
  callback(@Req() req:Request, @Res() res: Response) {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
}
```

strategy.ts:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Strategy,VerifyCallback } from 'passport-oauth2'
@Injectable()
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy,'oauth2') {
  constructor() {
    super({
      authorizationURL: 'www.example.com/login/connect/authorize',
      tokenURL: 'www.example.com/login/connect/token',
      clientID: 'client-id',
      clientSecret: 'client-secret',
      callbackURL: 'callback-url',
      passReqToCallback: true
    });
  }
async validate(accessToken: string, refreshToken: string, profile: any, done: VerifyCallback): Promise<any> {
  var user = {
    accessToken: accessToken,
    refreshToken: refreshToken,
    profile: profile
  };
  console.log(user);
  return done(null, user);
 }
}
```

strategy.ts is not invoking and not logging the user variable.

I tried to authenticate the user using passport-oauth2 package in nestjs.The problem is, strategy is not calling and not returning the user's accessToken.My expectation is strategy.ts file should return the accessToken and user.
And I'm not sure UseGuards(AuthGuard('oauth2')) is working. Any solutions please!

Answer (score 0):

The `validate` function does not run at all when:

1. the token is not set in the request
2. the token is not valid
3. the token expired
4. the token is encrypted but no `secretOrKey` is provided:

here in your example, the part when you create the token is missing so if you are using a secret key to encrypt the token you have to specify a `secretOrKey` property in the constructor of your `LocalStrategy` class and give it the same string value you encrypt your tokens with when you create them